# Binding collections in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding, viewmodel

I have a View Model that consists of an `Applicant` object and a `TeamMember` collection. When I post the model back the Team collection is always null. I've tried changing the collection from my original `IEnumarable` to a `List` but that didn't make a difference. So I changed the Controllers Edit Action to accept the `FormCollection`, and verified there was data in `viewModel["member.FirstName"]`. I'm lost as to why the binding isn't working. I tried to clean out my code samples as much as possible but I'm confused at what I'm missing. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**View Model Properties**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Applicant ApplicantInfo { get; set; }
    public List<TeamMember> TeamMembers { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
         //  viewModel.ApplicantInfo has the form data
         //  viewModel.TeamMembers = null              
}
```

**View**

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
       {%>
    <h3>
    <a href="#">Applicant Information</a>
    </h3>
    <label>
        City
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.ApplicantInfo.City)%>
    </label>
    <label>
        State
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.ApplicantInfo.State)%>
    </label>

    <h3>
    <a href="#">Team</a>
    </h3>
    <div>
    <% foreach (var member in Model.TeamMembers)
    { %>           
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.DropDownList("member.Type", Model.GetMemberTypes(member.MemberType.TypeId))%>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(m => member.FirstName)%>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(m => member.LastName)%>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(m => member.Title)%>
    </div>            
    <%} %>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
    <% } %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that input tags associated with items in a collection (when the model itself is not a collection) need to have an index in the name attribute before you can bind posted data to a view model.  Here is the way I usually accomplish this...

```
<% for (int i=0; i<Model.TeamMembers.Count; i++) { %>
<div class="editor-field">
  <%: Html.EditorFor(m => m.TeamMembers[i].FirstName)%>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
  <%: Html.EditorFor(m => m.TeamMembers[i].LastName)%>
</div>
<% } %>
```

I've also used the template as suggested by Shea, but I have a tad more code trying to force it to render brackets/indexes.

```
<% foreach (var member in Model.TeamMembers) { %>
  <%: Html.EditorFor(x => 
    member, 
    "TeamMember", 
    "TeamMembers["+(member.Number-1)+"]", 
    new { MemberTypes = Model.GetMemberTypes(member.MemberType.TypeId) })%>
<% } %>
```

Here is an [old but still relevant article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) from Phil Haack on the topic.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when I implemented my template I didn't need to worry about forcing indexes to display, etc. I believe when you use `EditorFor` on a list and you have an editor template for the individual items that make up the list, it automatically iterates and takes care of binding, etc.

Comment: I know it works without indexing when the model is itself a list.  However, I ran into problems without the indexing in the case where the model had a list as one of its properties.  I certainly advocate that the op give it a shot before discounting it though.  It looks alot cleaner without the brackets.

Comment: I tried doing it Shea's way first but it didn't seem to work. Now that I've read his post again, I think i miss understood him. I made a template accepting a `List<TeamMember>` instead of the `TeamMember` itself. Anyways I went with the index option and it worked great. I'm going to see if I can get it to work with the template when time permits. Thanks both of you!

Comment: Yeah, I ran into the same stumbling block. The template isn't for the list, it's for an individual list item. MVC iterates over the list and uses the editor template as many times as needed. It automagically prepends the ID of the list item with the name of the collection that owns it and the item's position in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(m => m.TeamMembers) %>
```

Then, make a shared editor template with a model type of `TeamMember`. MVC should handle binding everything back to your viewmodel on post for you.